# ¿Por qué al usar un bucle "do-while" imprime un tercer mensaje, cuando la condición deja de cumplirse?

Tags: java

El siguiente programa en Java, genera un número entero aleatorio entre 0 y 100 y luego pide al usuario ingresar números para intentar adivinarlo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdivinarNumero {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      int contador = 0;
      int numero;
      int aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
      

      do {
         System.out.print("\nFavor ingrese un número entero entre 0 y 100: ");
         numero = input.nextInt();

         if (numero > aleatorio)
            System.out.println("El número buscado es menor");
         else
            System.out.println("El número buscado es mayor");

         contador++;
      }
      while (numero != aleatorio); 

      System.out.println("\nAcertaste y lo intentaste " + contador + " veces!");
   }
}
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿por qué al usar un bucle `do-while` y "adivinar" el número, imprime ese tercer mensaje de "El número buscado es mayor", cuando la condición deja de cumplirse? O sea, "18 no es menor que 18", por lo tanto, ese tercer mensaje no debería de imprimirse y solamente debería de enviar el último mensaje diciendo que acertaste...

Este mismo ejercicio lo hice solamente con el bucle `while` y con este sí me funciona correctamente, mi intención es entender el porqué pasa lo que pasa.

```
Favor ingrese un número entero entre 0 y 100: 15
El número buscado es mayor

Favor ingrese un número entero entre 0 y 100: 20
El número buscado es menor

Favor ingrese un número entero entre 0 y 100: 18
El número buscado es mayor

Acertaste y lo intentaste 3 veces!
```

Comment: Te sucede porque el número que introduces no es mayor al aleatorio, es igual. y al salir del if, como no se cumple, se ejecuta siempre el else.

Comment: Agrega al `else` la condición `else if(numero < aleatorio)` y se resolverá tu problema.

Comment: al usar `else` esta diciendo que cualquier condicional que no sea `(numero>aleatorio)` que es el primer `if` se cumpla..incluyendo cuando aleatorio sea igual a numero,osea cuando se cumpla esa condición tambien se cumplira el `else` ,para evitar ello usa `else if(numero<aleatorio){"el numero buscado es mayor"};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código como ya te han comentado tendria que quedar asi. Tal como lo tienes al no cumplir la condicion del if siempre executara el código del else.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdivinarNumero {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  int contador = 0;
  int numero;
  int aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 100);

  int contador = 0;
          int numero;
          int aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
          

          do {
             System.out.print("\nFavor ingrese un número entero entre 0 y 100: \n");
             numero = sc.nextInt();
             
             if (numero > aleatorio)
                System.out.println("El número buscado es menor \n");
             else if (numero < aleatorio)
                System.out.println("El número buscado es mayor \n");

             contador++;
          }
          while (numero != aleatorio); 

          System.out.println("\nAcertaste y lo intentaste " + contador + " veces!");
   }
}
```